# Kotlin not nullable value can be null?

Tags: gson, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I have backend that return me some json.

I parse it to my class:

```
class SomeData(
  @SerializedName("user_name") val name: String,
  @SerializedName("user_city") val city: String,
  var notNullableValue: String
)
```

Use gson converter factory:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
  .client(okHttpClient)
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
  .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
  .build();
```

And in my interface:

```
interface MyAPI {
    @GET("get_data")
    Observable<List<SomeData>> getSomeData();
}
```

Then I retrieve data from the server (with rxJava) without any error. But I expected an error because I thought I should do something like this (to prevent GSON converter error, because `notNullableValue` is not present in my JSON response):

```
class SomeData @JvmOverloads constructor(
  @SerializedName("user_name") val name: String,
  @SerializedName("user_city") val city: String,
  var notNullableValue: String = ""
)
```

After the data is received from backend and parsed to my SomeData class with constructor without def value, the value of the **notNullableValue == null**.

As I understand not nullable value can be null in Kotlin?

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39963353/2196460

Comment: Its explain situation with def value in constructor. But in my situation I don have def value.

Comment: the `notNullableValue` was changed by gson after created. because it is `var` not `val`.

Comment: With val it's all the same. I try val too.

Comment: :), are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I'll find this with val, than change val to var and get the same behavior.

Comment: interesting. I'll try it later.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum verifiable example of the problem and post it somewhere on github?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, that is because you're giving it a default value. Ofcourse it will never be null. That's the whole point of a default value.

Remove `=""` from constructor and you will get an error.

Edit: Found the issue. GSON uses the magic `sun.misc.Unsafe` class which has an `allocateInstance` method which is obviously considered very `unsafe` because what it does is skip initialization (constructors/field initializers and the like) and security checks. So there is your answer why a Kotlin non-nullable field can be null. Offending code is in `com/google/gson/internal/ConstructorConstructor.java:223`

Some interesting details about the `Unsafe` class: http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/

Comment: No, as You read correct all works fine without  ="". And notNullableValue == null

Comment: I am sorry for misunderstanding, I am edit question.

Comment: @jQuick I updated my answer. TLDR: Gson is using unsafe java magic classes.

Comment: If you're unhappy with Gson behaviour of a non-nullable having a null value and prefer default value instead, you can use Jackson-kotlin-module. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426579/in-kotlin-jackson-deserialization-error-with-data-class

Comment: This is not only affecting the non-nullable type, but also, all of the properties that are initiated in the class body instead of primary constructor will not be initialized, aka null.

Answer (score 4):

Try to override constructor like this:

```
class SomeData(
        @SerializedName("user_name") val name: String,
        @SerializedName("user_city") val city: String,
        var notNullableValue: String = "") {
    constructor() : this("","","")
}
```

Now after server response you can check the **notNullableValue** is not null - its empty

Comment: This method not only solves the problem but also let you set the default value for the parameters.